# Detect changes on Stored Procedure result

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a Stored Procedure which returns multiple tables. I now need a way to get notified whenever a field which is contained in the SP changes. 
The basic tables get changed by a number of other sources, ranging from manual inserts to programms.

Do I need to put manual triggers on all tables which are used in the SP or is there a better, more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using teradata, you can use the below snippet after each of your dml statements :

SET lv_activity_count = activity_count;

SET lv_message = ' Number of rows merged in table1 is '|| lv_activity_count ;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not using teradata, I am using SQL Server 2012. As I said above, I have an SP (with joins etc.) which returns a couple of tables. I want to detect whether any data in the underlying tables of my SP changes.